# Wizard Page 'Select Destination Location': Change text depending on condition

Tags: inno-setup

I need to change the text defined in the message `SelectDirLabel3`, that is shown on the `Select Destination Location` wizard page depending on a condition known to the pascal code.

[image]

I searched for a possibility to overwrite the message `SelectDirLabel3` in the pascal code but I have not found a function to do that. I assume this can not be done.

An other possibility could be to edit the setup of the wizard page `Select Destination Location` with the `NextButtonClick()` function when `Next` is clicked on the previous wizard page. But I can not find any documentation how to do that (I just want to change the text of the message `SelectDirLabel3` in case the 'condition' is met!)

Maybe there is an other possibility to achieve my objective.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed cannot change `[Messages]` on runtime/conditionally.

But you can indeed change the control label. Just set `WizardForm.SelectDirLabel.Caption` as you need.